# How to create mysqli table using a constant?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am trying to create a table with mysqli and give it prefixed name using a pre-defined constant, but i can't get it to work would you please check the code and tell me what is wrong.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "users";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
define("TABLE_PREIX","xjk");

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE ".TABLE_PREIX."-users (
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(50),
        reg_date TIMESTAMP
        )";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

**Edit:**

Here is the error:

> Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-users ( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCH' at line 1

Comment: So which error message do you get?

Comment: "_but i can't get it to work_" What exactly doesn't work? Creating the table? (Does it already exist?) Have you echoed your query and run it in phpMyAdmin/mysql console? What does `$conn->error` say?

Comment: encapsulate the entire table name in backticks

Comment: @Sirko i have added the error

Comment: `xjk-users` is an invalid bare identifier and it needs to be backtick-quoted.

Comment: @RamRaider Would you please tell me how

Comment: I think i have found where the problem is, I should encapsulate the table name in backticks

Comment: like this: CREATE TABLE `".TABLE_PREIX."-users``